# Why doesn't Bootstrap5 tooltip work in other BS5 component?

Tags: bootstrap-5

So I'm trying to use tooltip component from BS5. But somehow it doesn't work. Let me show you the html code first.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <a class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="card-title">this is title.&nbsp;<span class="badge badge-theme" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="this is tooltip">Origiinal content</span></div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

What's weird is that when I place the tooltip outside the card component, the tooltip works perfectly. What is the problem? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a working example of a tooltip on a whole card:
[Working demo](https://playcode.io/897070)

Placing `id="example" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top"` in my demo on any element will result in the tooltip appearing on that element. In this case, I placed it on on the div with the class `.card`.

Feel free to change the id name from `example` to your desired id (in both script.js and index.html).